# Insert Date section DIV in between records HTML generated from JavaScript based on date of record

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an **Activity Log** of events from my Project Management application.

I would like to insert some HTML elements into the view of my Activity Log to show something similar to what **Windows File Explorer** shows when you sort files by Date...

See image below for a better understanding as it shows some files and folders in a Windows 7 file explorer.  In between them are the labels I am talking about

[image]

---

**List of Date values I need to calculate and get using JavaScipt**

- **Today**
- **Yesterday**
- **Earlier this Week**
- **Last Week**
- **Earlier this Month**
- **Earlier this Year**
- **A While Ago**

---

**My app shown below...**

So each activity row shown below is generated in JavaScript by calling a function which build the correct HTML based on the type of record it is from a JSON string.

I am thinking if I build some functions to compare dates I can process each row checking it's date for a match to one of my date sections mentioned above.

With that method if 3 records match for "yesterday" then it would make 3 DIV's with "Yesterday".

To prevent this, I am thinking maybe I can have a variable for each date section and once 1 record matches, set the variable to "true"

Once a date section is "true" it will start looking for the next date section to insert.

Does this sound like the way to do this or is there another way?

Keeping in mind that each row/record is added to the HTML when it runs through a JavaScript function?

[image]

Comment: Tried adding `class`, e.g., "yesterday" to elements with "Yesterday" records , wrap each day, date, period in parent element , style each parent element to have space between next ?

Comment: if you are worried about making to many of the same dividers then one idea is to make the dividers first then based on switch (date) /case.. to insert the posts one by one in the dividers

Answer (score 1):

You said: "I am thinking maybe I can have a variable for each date section and once 1 record matches, set the variable to 'true'".

Why not use an object?

```
`pseudo-code`
var labels = {}; // Today, Yesterday, Earlier this Week, etc

function createDivs(date, row) {
    labels[date] = labels[date] || [];
    labels[date].push(row);
}
```

You could loop through your data and the object will be self-aware if the key exists or not and the data is always appended to the correct label.

Comment: This approach sounds promising.  I don't fully understand it 100% yet though.  It appears to me that the date label would then show up on every row instead of being more like section headings?  I Can see how it would make sue each record was in the correct section.  Just not sure how to limit it to only showing the top 1st occurrence of the label name for each section

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `dl` , `dt` , `dd` , `time` elements ; `css`

```css
[id] {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:24px;
  color:blue;  
}

dd {
  padding:4px;
  color:green;
}

time {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt id="yesterday">Yesterday</dt>
  <dd class="yesterday">Changed stuff at a <time>12/13/2021</time></dd>
  <dd class="yesterday">Changed stuff at b <time>12/12/2021</time></dd>
</dl>
```